# Is it always safe to remove and add back padding on base64 strings?

Tags: encoding, base64

Here's some Python code which has worked for all my test cases. Are there any corner cases where this would not work?

```
import base64
def test(in_value):
    encoded = base64.b64encode(in_value).rstrip('=')
    out_value = base64.b64decode(encoded + '=' * (4 - len(encoded) % 4))
    assert out_value == in_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Base64 ignores whitespace, but your algorithm depends on not having any extra characters in the string.